# Goursat Problem Solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations, hyperbolic-equations

Show that the equation $u_{xy}+u_x=0$, $x\leq x_0$, $y\leq y_0$ has the solution $\alpha(x)e^{-y}+\beta(y)$ where $\alpha,\beta$ are arbitrary single variable functions.

I have understood that I can integrate wrt $x$ to get $u_y+u=\gamma(y)$ and I am stuck there.

Answer (score 2):

$$u_{xy}+u_x=0$$
Substitute $u_x=p$ 
$$\frac  {dp}{dy}+p=0$$
$$\int \frac  {dp}{p}=-\int dy = -y+c(x)$$
$$\ln p=- y+c(x)$$
$$u_x=e^{- y}c(x)$$
$$\int du =\int e^{- y}c(x)dx$$
$$u(x,y) = e^{- y}\int c(x)dx$$
$$\boxed{u(x,y) = e^{- y}(K(x)+P (y))}$$

Comment: Do you have an introductory reference book for first order nonlinear PDEs? Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

$$u_y+u=\gamma(y)$$
This a first order linear ODE (no $dx$ in it)  $\frac{du}{dy}+u(y)=\gamma(y)$ .

The solution of the associated homogeneous ODE, $\frac{du}{dy}+u=0$ is $u=c\:e^{-y}$

Replacing the constant $c$ by an unknown function $v(y)$ leads to $u=e^{-y}v(y)$ ,
$$u_y+u=e^{-y}(-v+v')+e^{-y}v=e^{-y}v'=\gamma(y)$$
$$\frac{dv}{dy}=e^y\gamma(y)$$
$v(y)=\int e^y\gamma(y)dy=f(y)+$constant relatively to $y$.
$$v(x,y)=f(y)+\alpha(x)$$
$u(x,y)=e^{-y}v(x,y)=e^{-y}\left(f(y)+\alpha(x) \right)$
$$u(x,y)=\beta(y)+e^{-y}\alpha(x)$$
with $\beta(y)=e^{-y}f(y)$

Comment: Do you have an introductory reference book for non-linear first order PDEs?